# Why does setting comboBox.SelectedIndex fail to change what appears in the editable portion of my ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, keydown

I have a C# Winform app. It has a `ComboBox`. My goal is to have the item selected in the `ComboBox` drop down appear in the editable portion of the `ComboBox` when the `delete` key is typed. For example, if the `ComboBox` has items `A`, `B`. and `C`, then item `A` is displayed when the `Form` is loaded. If I click the drop down, hover over item `C`, and then type the `delete` key, I want the drop down list to be dismissed and `C` to appear in the editable portion of the `ComboBox`.

As it is, I've verified that I am getting the selected item text, but the line of code `comboBox.SelectedIndex = comboBox.FindStringExact(selectedItemText);` does not change what appears in the editable portion of the `ComboBox`

MCVE:

Note: form has a combobox named `combobox` and a textbox named `textbox`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Winforms_Scratch
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //using string collection because I need to simulate what is returned from an Application Settings list
            StringCollection computerList = new StringCollection { "C", "B", "A" };

            ArrayList.Adapter(computerList).Sort();

            comboBox.DataSource = computerList;

            comboBox.KeyDown += ComboBox_KeyDown;

            computerList = null;

        }

        private void ComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete && comboBox.DroppedDown)
            {
                ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;

                //get the text of the item in the dropdown that was selected when the Delete key was pressed
                string selectedItemText = comboBox.GetItemText(comboBox.SelectedItem);

                //take focus away from the combobox to force it to dismiss the dropdown
                this.Focus();

                //load selectedItemText into the textbox just so we can verify what it is
                textBox.Text = selectedItemText;

                //set the comboBox SelectedIndex to the index of the item that matches the  
                //text of the item in the dropdown that was selected when the Delete key was pressed
                comboBox.SelectedIndex = comboBox.FindStringExact(selectedItemText);
                comboBox.Refresh();

                //Stop all further processing
                e.Handled = true;

            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down && !comboBox.DroppedDown)
            {
                //If the down arrow is pressed show the dropdown list from the combobox
                comboBox.DroppedDown = true;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `comboBox.FindStringExact(selectedItemText);` returns what you expect?

Comment: @JuanR: `As it is, I've verified that I am getting the selected item text`

Comment: That is not what I asked. I asked what the return value of `FindStringExact` is.

Comment: @JuanR: My apologies. Yes, `comboBox.FindStringExact(selectedItemText);` returns the index that corresponds to `selectedItemText `

Comment: OK.... so what is the value???

Comment: Just so you know, I am not being annoying. There is a reason I ask these things. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: ???. Its the index that corresponds to `selectedItemText`. if `A` is selected, then 0. `B`, 1. `C`, 2. (Note that the input list is sorted before its loaded into the combobox)

Comment: I think your problem may be that you are refreshing the combo box after you set the index. Remove `comboBox.Refresh();`. I don't think you need to do that. Also, I don't think you need this: `e.Handled = true;`.

Comment: Set `comboBox.DroppedDown = false;` instead of focusing the window. Then set `comboBox.SelectedItem = selectedItemText;`

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Nice one. That might be it.

Comment: One change needed: Changing `this.Focus()` to `comboBox.DroppedDown = false` did the trick (Ed: Please provide this as the answer). The Microsoft property doc on `DroppedDown` is pretty terse. I guess there is something it does that is not done when the combobox  just loses focus? (I mean, this.Focus() causes the dropdown to be dismissed too).  Removing or leaving `comboBox.Refresh()` has no effect either way. I'll leave `e.Handled = true` because I do not want this event to propogate any farther. i.e, to the default control handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the combobox behaves differently after it loses focus. In any case, I made the following changes and it works, according to my understanding of your requirements. You can call `this.Focus()` after setting the selected item, if there's a separate requirement to return focus to the window. Your SelectedIndex/FindStringExact approach works identically to setting SelectedItem to the string.

I got rid of the text box, since as I understand it that's just for debugging purposes.

```
private void ComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete && comboBox.DroppedDown)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;

        //  Get the text of the item in the dropdown that was selected when the 
        //  Delete key was pressed
        string selectedItemText = comboBox.GetItemText(comboBox.SelectedItem);

        comboBox.DroppedDown = false;

        comboBox.SelectedItem = selectedItemText;

        //Stop all further processing
        e.Handled = true;

    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down && !comboBox.DroppedDown)
    {
        //  If the down arrow is pressed show the dropdown list from the combobox
        comboBox.DroppedDown = true;
    }
}
```